# Why there is no color appeared on my nav bar when using "padding: 10px ; !imprtant; "

Tags: html, css

Please help ,i am new at this and this is confuses me. When i remove this line the color is back but when i use it it just dissapear. I am trying to follow some tutorial on how to make a website from youtube but this line just doesnt work with me!

Why there is no color appeared on my nav bar when using 
`padding: 10px ; !important;`

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    
    }
    
    #nav-bar {
    
        position: sticky;
        top 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #800000, #B22222)
            padding: 10px ; !important; 
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Scarlet Botique</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <section id="nav-bar">
    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/icon.png"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-togger-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Location</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
    
        </section>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

```
<!-- 7:34 min https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0IgI8vYD_o&list=PLjwm_8O3suyMKWZwlgptQtfCShqZ2syV5 -->
```

Thankyou in advance !

Comment: missing `;` at the end of the background

Comment: it should be !important, and you can also cut the ";" between the padding value and the !important

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are missing a semicolon after your background.

`background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #800000, #B22222);`

is what is should be.

In your next line, you have one semicolon too much and you misspelled important... BTW, you should generally try to avoid using `!important`. You don't seem to need it anyway in your case :).

Comment: ...may I ask why me and the other answer were downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes try to fix it:

```
#nav-bar {

    position: sticky;
    top: 0;  // Add : here.
    z-index: 10;
}


.navbar {

        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #800000, #B22222);// Add ; here.
        padding: 10px ; 
}
```